# Rails: How to choose which js file a controller action to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I know the fact that by default Rails chooses the javascript file depending on action's name to render:

For example if I have

```
def create
     #Code and Stuff happening here
end
```

and here I have

```
create.js.erb
```

which will be ran by default

But is there a way that I can choose a different javascript file to be rendered from inside the action ?

For example

```
create1.js.erb
create2.js.erb
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to add something like the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :create1 }
end
```

Alternately, if you had a different path to it besides the default you could use:

```
format.js { render :file => "/path/to/save.js.erb" }
```

If it is a more dynamic requirement than this, you could always use string interpolation or "string".to_sym to render the desired view.

Comment: Mike ? You are a champion! Thanks! Thank you so much!